# System 32 powershell command

Tags: windows, powershell, operating-system, system

[image]
Someone sent me a link to download a file that i needed but i was very skeptical of it so i decided to open the link file in an emulator and this was inside of it. What does this do? and how could it have affected my computer?

Comment: It downloads an executable and seems to be overwriting your svchost.exe with it (a very crucial windows component).
I think you where right to be skeptical about this because this looks very fishy.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever sent you that link is either ignorant or malicious (in either case *not to be trusted*)

> What does this do?

It downloads an executable file from `fu wa.se` (intentional spacing to prevent anyone from visiting), saves it to the users AppData folder as `svchost.exe` (common malware hiding technique) and then launches said executable with `imageres.dll` as its argument.

> and how could it have affected my computer?

Anything - you just downloaded and ran an untrusted executable.

`imageres.dll` has been the victim of RCE vulnerabilities in the past due to autoloading in `explorer.exe` - this way an attacker can hide a piece of malware on your machine and have it automatically execute when you browse a specific folder.